# Is there a way to use a variable in multiple classes in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

If I define a variable in one class file, is there a way to access the same variable in another class?

Comment: You need to be more precise on this question because the amount of possible of answer is very large and may not fit your real needs. Please provide the pattern in where you want to share variables.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Class1
{
    static const int myInteger = 256;
}

class Class2
{
    private void myMethod()
    {
        int i = Class1.myInteger;
        //i is now 256.
    }
}
```

You can declare the variable as static at the topmost scope of your first class (Class1). See the MSDN article for more information regarding `static` members:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a reference to an object of the first class. Or if that variable is a public static member of the first class, in which case you don't need am object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provide access to it via a Property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Variables should be exposed as public properties or fields if you want to access them through other classes. However these classes need a relationship.

```
public class C1
{
  public int x = 1;
}

public class C2
{
  private C1 otherClass;

  // constructor
  public C2(C1 other)
  {
    this.otherClass = other;
  }

  public void accessOtherClass()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(this.otherClass.x);
  }
}
```